# When you press the keyfob lock button and the car is already locked, why does it make the sound of bolts moving?

Tags: security, central-locking

Obviously the bolts would move when the car is first locked, but when it is already locked, surely they do not need to move again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sound comes from the solenoids hitting the stops as they are re-energised, even though they do not move much.